# How to show two routes using Google Directions Service?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let say there is a journey A -> B

Approach:

1) Geocode A.Address and B.Address

2) Use A.LatLng and B.LatLng to calculate the route, display it and show distance

3) Do 1) and 2) for return journey B -> A

Let say in my case route A -> B is not equal B -> A I would like to show both routes on one map in same time. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried this and did it work,or not?

Comment: DirectionsRenderer has setDirections(directions:DirectionsResult) method what I need is to set two DirectionsResult in one go. I think I know how to do it "hard way". I can have two DirectionsResults and switch between them manually, but do not know how to dispaly two routes same time in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2 routes you need  2 `DirectionsRenderer`s with different names.

Call the second after the  first request.